# Is there a way to find if a sequence of two chars are found in a list only if they are consecutive?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am currently working in the elm syntax. An example would be like this:

(Sequence ('a') ('b')) ('c') ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] . In this example, i only test if the elements 'a', 'b', 'c' are members of the list. If yes, then i partition it and obtain (['a','b','c'],['d'])

I **encountered problems** in the following case:

```
 (Sequence ('a') ('b')) ('c') ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

obtaining the result :
(['a','b','c','a'],[])

**My question is**: what **condition** should i put such that the elements 'a' and 'b' **must be consecutive** avoiding the case when they are matched alone?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Try to explain what you want in what might seem like excessive detail. Provide multiple examples. Try to "think like a lawyer" about your description; are there any loopholes? This will help others help you, and even more, it will help you learn yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the alone element 'a' will also be taken.*"? I'd suggest you try writing a recursive function that does pattern matching on the first two elements of the respective list.

Comment: @dfeuer i tried to edit the question with my results and the case which concerns me, i hope it's more clear now

Comment: In your example Problem do you want to receive `(['a','b','c'],['a'])`, but you get `(['a','b','c','a'],[])`? Or do you want to get the second? Can you post your current code? E.g. to htttps://ellie-app.com

Comment: Note that, if this is supposed to be Elm code, you don't need any of those parentheses, and the function name must start with a lower case letter.

Comment: No, the question is still not clear. You talk a lot about one example. But you don't explain anywhere what the overall general idea is, and you only give *one* example. Sometimes people can do a good job of guessing what you want if you give a wide variety of different examples, but extrapolating from one, without a solid overview, is basically impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that if you have `Sequence 'a' 'b' 'c'` and test it against the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`, you want to receive the result `(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a'])` (as asked in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458918/is-there-a-way-to-find-if-a-sequence-of-two-chars-are-found-in-a-list-only-if-th#comment113981366_64458918)).

In pseudo-code:

1. Split the list into two, `list1` and `list2`. `list1` should have the same length as your sequence. Elm provides [List.take](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#take) and [List.drop](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#drop) for that
2. Convert your sequence into a list `list_sequence` with a helper function
3. Test if `list1` and `list_sequence` are equal
4. If they are, return the tuple `(list1, list2)`

And here is the actual Elm code:
https://ellie-app.com/bjBLns4dKkra1

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that tests if a sequence of elements occurs in a list:

```
module Main exposing (main)
 
import Html exposing (Html, text)


containsSeq : List a -> List a -> Bool
containsSeq seq list =
    let
        helper remainingSeq remainingList savedSeq savedList =
            case remainingSeq of
                [] ->
                    True

                x :: xs ->
                    case remainingList of
                        [] ->
                            False

                        y :: ys ->
                            if x == y then
                                helper xs ys (savedSeq ++ [ x ]) (savedList ++ [ y ])

                            else
                                case savedList of
                                    [] ->
                                        helper (savedSeq ++ remainingSeq) ys [] []

                                    y2 :: y2s ->
                                        helper (savedSeq ++ remainingSeq) (y2s ++ remainingList) [] []
    in
    helper seq list [] []


main =
    text <| Debug.toString <| containsSeq [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] [ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

This only checks if the sequences appears and the type of the elements have to be `comparable`.

Here is the above function altered to return a partitioning of the old list as a 3 elements Tuple with (elementsBefore, sequence, elementsAfter). The result is wrapped in a `Maybe` so that if the sequence is not found, it returns `Nothing`.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (Html, text)


partitionBySeq : List a -> List a -> Maybe ( List a, List a, List a )
partitionBySeq seq list =
    let
        helper remainingSeq remainingList savedSeq savedCurrentList savedOldList =
            case remainingSeq of
                [] ->
                    Just ( savedOldList, seq, remainingList )

                x :: xs ->
                    case remainingList of
                        [] ->
                            Nothing

                        y :: ys ->
                            if x == y then
                                helper xs ys (savedSeq ++ [ x ]) (savedCurrentList ++ [ y ]) savedOldList

                            else
                                case savedCurrentList of
                                    [] ->
                                        helper (savedSeq ++ remainingSeq) ys [] [] (savedOldList ++ [ y ])

                                    y2 :: y2s ->
                                        helper (savedSeq ++ remainingSeq) (y2s ++ remainingList) [] [] (savedOldList ++ [ y ])
    in
    helper seq list [] [] []


main =
    text <| Debug.toString <| partitionBySeq [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] [ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

Of course, if you are only dealing with characters, you might as well convert the list into a `String` using `String.fromList` and use `String.contains "abc" "ababcd"` for the first version and `String.split "abc" "ababcd"` to implement the second one.